# Terraform setting options for a variable dynamically

Tags: terraform

I am converting a AWS CloudFormation to Terraform template.

When I am creating a VPC in AWS CloudFormation I can set a pre-defined values, such as the Availability Zones, enabling me to choose which Availability Zones to use in certain deployment, like below:

```yaml
Parameters:
  AvailabilityZones:
    Description: 'List of Availability Zones to use for the subnets in the VPC. Note:
      The logical order is preserved.'
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name>
```

[image]

**What can be done in Terraform to simulate this behavior (pre-defined values based on a list of given values)?**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Normally you'd just deploy resources to a whole region and have your Terraform code spread that across availability zones.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm trying to construct a generic Terraform script where I can deploy with 1 to n AZs, This behavior It's normal in AWS CloudFormation.

Comment: That's not how you would do that with Terraform. Instead you'd accept a count of how many resources you want and automatically spread them across all of the availability zones in the region. I'm not really sure what you're suggesting is even good practice in CloudFormation but it's been a long time since I've done much with it.

Comment: Ultimately you could provide an input variable that accepts availability zone identifiers in some form (either as `us-east-2a` or just `a` and concatenate it with the region) but I'd be questioning why you think your users need to determine which AZs thing should run in and instead just have things spread across all of the AZs in the region.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I based my template in https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/vpc/ 

If I use all AZs, I will launch a lot of NAT (7 in us-east-1), and I don't want to be charged for It in all cases (dev account for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most direct analog to this CloudFormation feature in Terraform is [Input Variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html), which allow you to define something essentially equivalent to what you have in CloudFormation:

```
variable "availability_zone" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of Availability Zones to use for the subnets in the VPC. Note: The logical order is preserved."
}
```

One difference compared to CloudFormation is that Terraform doesn't have a first-class type for "availablity zone name", and so a string containing the name is how the AWS provider's typical representation of an availability zone.

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking but I think you were also asking about the specific CloudFormation UI you took a screenshot of, where the UI itself understands the concept of an availability zone and so it can provide extra help like autocompletion. Terraform module input variables are typically configured in code rather than via a web UI, so there isn't any direct analog to that CloudFormation feature in Terraform.

Comment: Input variables can also be required or overridden on the command line, which brings the analog a little closer.